# DbUnit Tests with SilkCentral

Tags: testing, junit, dbunit, silk-central

I´m trying to execute DbUnit Tests with SilkCentral in a remote Virtual Machine that works like a execution server. The Alltests.class directory is in `\\p6621va\ucd\ucdmain_TEST\bin\es\bde\aps\ucdmain\ias\tests\AllTests.class` and it contents the suiteTests.
I need to specify the AllTests.class Classpath , I`ve done like this according the documentation:

[image]

It returns the following error:

[image]

How can I specify the Classpath?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the class with its package and the classpath without.

Classpath: \p6621va\ucd\ucdmain_TEST\bin.
Test class: es.bde.aps.ucdmain.ias.tests.AllTests